# small question about gram schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I tried to find an answer online first, so excuse me if this question was asked before,

but, is the result of the gram schmidt process different, depending on the order that I go over the vectors in the original group?

I think it is, but i could not find a formal proof for it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is. Try running the proces on $[1,0]$ and $[1,1]$ in two different orders.

Comment: Can you also show a formal proof?

Comment: Perform Gramm-schmidt's process on the vectors I provided. It is not hard, and the result will be $2$ different pairs of orthogonal vectors. This will prove that the result of the process depends on the order.